# Evaluating value of run_dag.conf

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm very new to airflow, and have been playing with it on GCP.

I'm modifying the example at https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf that shows how a DAG can be invoked by a cloud function.

That simple DAG just prints the content of `run_dag.conf` using the bash operator.

I'm now trying to get the value of `run_dag.conf['bucket']` and `run_dag.conf['name']` in order to create an example where I use the CloudSqlImportOperator.

My problem is that it seems that I can't find a way to get those values to be passed as part of the `body` on the operator.

My understanding is that jinja templates get evaluated at the operators. My first attempt was to do:

```
import_body = {
    "importContext": {
        "fileType": "csv",
        "database": "dw",
        "uri": "gs://{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}/{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}",
        "csvImportOptions": {
            "table": "SHAKESPEARE",
            "columns": ["word", "word_count", "corpus", "corpus_date"]
        }
    }
}
```

And that fails because the jinja template section never gets evaluated, and the operator receives a literal  `"gs://{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}/{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}"` instead.

I tried to pass a string instead:

```
import_body = """{
    "importContext": {
        "fileType": "csv",
        "database": "dw",
        "uri": "gs://{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}/{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}",
        "csvImportOptions": {
            "table": "SHAKESPEARE",
            "columns": ["word", "word_count", "corpus", "corpus_date"]
        }
    }
}"""
```

And still I'm getting an error now : `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

I've seen examples using the PythonOperator and kwargs to fetch the contents, but so far no example of reading the contents of that dag_run.conf object inside the code.

What would be a proper way of doing that?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the [example you mentioned](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#trigger_response_dagpy), the jinja template is passed to the parameter `bash_command` which is a [templated field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L53). If you look at the [python operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L65) source code you can see that the only templated parameter is `templated_dict` so you to make airflow evaluate the `{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}` you need to pass it through this variable. I am shooting into the dark here because you did not post the full code but the solution should be something like the following:

Inside the python code that your python operator call (works with python3):

```py
import_body = f'''{
    "importContext": {
        "fileType": "csv",
        "database": "dw",
        "uri": "gs://{templated_dict['bucket']}/{templated_dict['name']}",
        "csvImportOptions": {
            "table": "SHAKESPEARE",
            "columns": ["word", "word_count", "corpus", "corpus_date"]
        }
    }
}'''
```

when you define the python operator in the DAG:

```
python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id=f'task_id',
    python_callable=my_func,
    provide_context=True,
    templated_dict={
        "bucket": "{{ dag_run.conf['bucket'] }}",
        "name": "{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Note that I referenced to the airflow version `1.10.2`, which I assume you are running because you tagged google cloud composer and this is the latest version supported.
If you look at [1.10.3](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L69) you can see that `op_args` and `op_kwargs` are added to the templated fields of the python operator. So in the next version update, you will be able to pass it as ousing also those.